# What are an internal and external exons?

Tags: genetics, terminology, splicing, exons

I read the book: [Essential Genetics and Genomics](http://samples.jblearning.com/9781284152456/9781284136609_TGxx_HartlEssn7e.pdf) It has a table summarizing the properties of the "typical" human gene:

[image: Table9.2 "Characteristics of Human Genes" from "Essential Genetics and Genomics"]

It has a gene feature `Size of internal exon`, what internal means in this context?

When I searched for it I found mentions about *external exons*, but found no definition.

I strongly suspect they mean:

<s>External exons are the first exon right after the 5' untranslated region and the last exon just before the 3' untranslated region and all the other exons are internal exons.</s>

As turned out this was almost right, but had a mistake which is wonderfully pointed out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the internal exons are those that aren't at the ends, which are often referred to as *terminal exons*<sup>1</sup>.

However, [exons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exon) are sequences of nucleotides that are incorporated into the mature mRNA — i.e. they don't have to be (entirely) protein coding.

It is probably simplest to think of exons as being the transcribed regions that are **not** [introns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intron) — i.e. they are the sequences that don't get spliced out during transcript maturation.

In other words, the 5'UTR is typically§ *part of* the first exon and the 3' UTR is typically§ *part of* the last exon.

§Note: I say typically, because sometimes introns are found within the UTRs<sup>2,3</sup>.

### Reference:

1: [Bolisetty, M. T., & Beemon, K. L. (2012). Splicing of internal large exons is defined by novel cis-acting sequence elements. Nucleic acids research, 40(18), 9244-9254.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3467050/)

2: [Eden, E., & Brunak, S. (2004). Analysis and recognition of 5′ UTR intron splice sites in human pre‐mRNA. Nucleic acids research, 32(3), 1131-1142.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC373407/)

3: [Paolantoni, C., Ricciardi, S., De Paolis, V., Okenwa, C., Catalanotto, C., Ciotti, M. T., ... & Giorgi, C. (2018). Arc 3′ UTR splicing leads to dual and antagonistic effects in fine-tuning arc expression upon BDNF signaling. Frontiers in molecular neuroscience, 11, 145.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnmol.2018.00145/full)

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer and references.

Comment: You're very welcome! 